# why store() in laravel change the file name in storage?

Tags: laravel, store

I have this code in laravel to store an image but why does the image name change when I checked it on the folder ?! Please help me I'm really frustrated !

```
public function postStore(Request $req){//Bikin toko baru


        $req->image->store('images','public');
        

        $req->validate([
            'name'=>['string','min:5'],
            'address'=>['string','min:10'],
            'description'=>['string','min:20']
            // 'image'=>'mimes:jpg,png,jpeg'

        ]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try this

```
$path = $request->file('image')->storeAs(
        'images', $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName()
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

From [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/requests#storing-uploaded-files):

> The store method accepts the path where the file should be stored relative to the filesystem's configured root directory. This path should not contain a file name, since a unique ID will automatically be generated to serve as the file name.

If you do not want a file name to be automatically generated, you may use the storeAs method, which accepts the path, file name, and disk name as its arguments:

```php
$path = $request->image->storeAs('images', 'filename.jpg');
$path = $request->image->storeAs('images', 'filename.jpg', 'public');
```